# Enable SSH into Mac Desktop from Mac Laptop ONLY for one user

Tags: mac, ssh, remote-access

I'm trying to enable SSH on my desktop in System Preferences/Sharing without "Allow access for All users." I just want to allow access for my admin account on my laptop. They're on the same network. How do I go about adding the admin account on my laptop to "Only these users."

Answer (score 0):

You can only specify local user accounts there, so you can only put users that are already on the laptop. If `laptop-username` is the admin user on the laptop, then choose "Only these users" and use the default inclusion of "Administrators." From the desktop mac's Terminal, regardless of what desktop user you're logged in as, simply `ssh laptop-username@laptop`.